# How to iterate if first child node matches move to next node in Java code

Tags: java, xml, selenium, pom.xml

```
<parent>         
  <child1>FIN </child1>
  <child2>Age 13</child2>
  <child3>Chennai</child3>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child1>FRE</child1>
  <child2>Age 15</child2>
  <child3>Delhi</child3>
</parent>
```

This is the XML which I am using. I need to get a value child3 node if my child1 node is matches in Java code. If FIN is matches, I need to get a value of child3 "Chennai". I'm using DoumentBuilderFactory to read XML.
Help me to solve this `logic.looking` for a Java coding.

```
for( int i = 0; i< PatientVariables.length; i++){
  // loop the staff child node
  NodeList patientlist = PatientVariables[i].getChildNodes();

  for (int i = 0; i < patientlist.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = patientlist.item(i);
```

Comment: Post the complete code which you have already written.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Instead of hand crafted html, update the question with text based actual html.

Answer (score 0):

If your complete XML looks like that (please note I've added the root element and deleted the space after `FIN` for simplicity)

```
<root>
       <parent>         
       <child1>FIN</child1>
       <child2>Age 13</child2>
       <child3>Chennai</child3>
       </parent>
       <parent>
       <child1>FRE</child1>
       <child2>Age 15</child2>
       <child3>Delhi</child3>
       </parent>
</root>
```

you can find the element you are looking for by xpath:
`//parent/child1[text()='FIN']/following-sibling::child3`

Comment: I need java coding

Comment: have a look at how to use xpath with java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java